# Using ref with props

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a *Component A* with a nested *Component B*. *Component A* loads a list of strings, *Component B* has a `SELECT` element, which is populated when *Component A* is finished loading. The first option of the `SELECT` should be selected at this moment. After this moment, when other options are selected, *Component B* should emit `update` event with selection data, so that *Component A* 'knows' what option was selected. Since *A* should control *B*, this option is passed back to *B* with props.

In my implementation below, only the initial value of the selection is received by Component B, and when the list is loaded, it is populated successfully, but the selectedOption value is not changed by the controlling property. So, it doesn't work.

What would be a proper way to implement this?

*Component A*:

```html
<template>
  <component-b :list="list" :selected="selected" @update="onUpdate">
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue';
export default defineComponent({
  setup: () => {
    const list = ref<string[]>([]);
    const selected = ref('');

    load().then(data => {       // some load function returning a promise
      selected.value = data[0]; // data is never empty
      list.value = data;
    });

    const onUpdate = (data: string) => selected.value = data;

    return { list, selected, onUpdate };
  }
})
</script>
```

*Component B*:

```html
<template>
  <select v-model="selectedOption" @change="onChange">
    <option v-for="item of props.list" />{{item}</option>
  </select>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref, PropType } from 'vue';
export default defineComponent({
  emits: ['update'],
  props: {
    selected: {
      type: String
    },
    list: {
      type: Object as PropType<String[]>
    }
  }
  setup: (props, { emit }) => {
    const selectedOption = ref(props.selected); // this doesn't work when loading is finished and props are updated
    
    const onChange = () => emit('update', selectedOption.value);

    return { selectedOption, onChange, props }
  }
});
</script>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `ComponentB.vue`, `selectedOption`'s `ref` is only *initialized* to the value of `props.selected`, but that itself is *not reactive* (i.e., the `ref` isn't going to track `props.selected` automatically):

```js
const selectedOption = ref(props.selected); // not reactive to props.selected
```

You can resolve this with a [`watchEffect`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#watcheffect) that copies any new values to `selectedOption` (which happens automatically whenever `props.selected` changes):

```js
watchEffect(() => selectedOption.value = props.selected);
```

**Side note:** `setup()` doesn't need to explicitly return `props` because they're already available to the template by name. Your template could be changed to:

```html
<!-- <option v-for="item of props.list">{{ item }}</option> -->

                         reference props directly by name
<option v-for="item of list">{{ item }}</option>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-update-a-prop-copy?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FComponentB.vue)

Answer (score 0):

In component B, you shouldn't need to add both a v-model and a @change.

```
 <select :value="selected" @change="onChange">
   <option v-for="item in list">{{ item }}</option>
 </select>
```

Then in the onChange get the value from the select and emit up:

```
const onChange = (event) => emit('update', event.target.value);
```